# Could not proxy request /pusher/auth from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a chat app using reactJS and pusher, i am getting this error-

> Could not proxy request /pusher/auth from localhost:3000 to
>   http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)

in package.json file i have set proxy as-

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

and my `localhost` is defined as `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` file.
I have also checked for the port availability using `netstat`, but these all seems to be correct. Can anybody help?

Comment: you server is not start,you probably just npm start

Comment: did you get a solution?
I have the same issue and none of the answers here work

Comment: Actually in my case I was getting this issue because of wrong url e.g. I was using `/api/note/<id>/` instead of `/api/notes/<id>/`

Comment: Just needed to restart the server.

Answer (score 66):

I had a same problem in my React App and I fixed it by just adding `/` after the port number in package.json file (so now it's: "proxy": `http://localhost:5000/`)

Comment: Don't think this would work because this only fixes if the user is not adding a slash when using the route in the frontend. Adding the slash just makes it so you do not need to add that beginning slash in any of your routes in your react app

Comment: for me removing the '/'  solved the issue

Comment: It worked temporarily. Same problem again after a fresh npm start.

Answer (score 41):

I faced a similar issue but in Mac machine. I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and that worked for me.

For windows:

```
"proxy": {
  "/auth/google": {
    "target": "localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

For Mac:

```
"proxy": {
  "/auth/google": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked, no idea why. On curl they are both solved...

Comment: Didn't work for me on mac.

Comment: I confirm that using localhost as a proxy host is a problem on Mac. Using 127.0.0.1 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. I have a Mac and changing to `127.0.0.1` fixed it. Could anyone explain this in detail? Would love to know.

Answer (score 21):

In your server package.json add `--ignore client` to your "start" or "server" scripts. So it would look like this:

```
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node index.js",
 "server": "nodemon index.js --ignore client"
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was trying to fix this bug for hours.

Comment: How did you know to do this?

Comment: Hi, I don’t exactly remember how I figured it out, since it was quite a while ago. But I do remember narrowing the problem down to nodemon and looking through the internet to find configurations and picking the most logical ones to test. I hope that answers your thought process question. Most importantly I believe it was knowing what to ask that led me to an acceptable solution.

Comment: Lifesaver! This flag works with react-scripts as well: `react-scripts start --ignore client`

Answer (score 17):

I think You have not start your Back end server. Try start both Back end and Front end server concurrently. Just simply run `npm start` in both back end and front end.

Answer (score 15):

In server directory

```
npm install --save http-proxy-middleware
```

then create a file with this name : setupProxy.js
in src directory of client react folder

[image]

then add the following

[image]

```js
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api/**", { // https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware
    target: "http://localhost:5000",
    secure: false
  }));
};
```

In proxy configuration make sure you are matching any path
with double ** not only *

**Note: you are not going to require this proxy anywhere else
just like that**

**Note: remove any other proxy settings in package.json**
For more check this [reference](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: Note: You do not need to import this file anywhere. It is automatically registered when you start the development server.

Answer (score 7):

In your node module include

```
{
...
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
}
```

*Where the ... simply means you should append the proxy ip to it.*

Also, if you are using axios, doing `axios.post('api/users')` works and not `axios.post('/api/users')`

Comment: I am using fetch so should I use  '/ ' or not

Answer (score 6):

For those who are using Docker, if your `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - 3000:xxxx
    ...
  api:
    ...
    ports:
      - 5000:xxxx
    ...
```

Then we should set the proxy URL to

```json
  "proxy": "http://host.docker.internal:5000"
```

Comment: Very good...but one question, will this also work when you deploy the stuff?

Comment: @Front-endDeveloper As stated in the doc https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/, "proxy" is only available in the development environment.

Answer (score 5):

In package.json file just add "/" after the port number and it should work fine.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

Answer (score 4):

I have similar issue.
The problem was that server was listening on ipv6 ::1 address 
and the proxy was connecting to ipv4 127.0.0.1

I changed both addresses from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Use 
**"proxy":"http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER/"**
in package.json

and in axios backend call route like
use **axios.get("api/user/getinfo")** instead of **axios.get("/api/user/getinfo")**;

Answer (score 3):

None of these answers were helping me despite everyone's effort. Finally, thankfully, I found [this](https://github.com/plouc/mozaik/issues/118) github discussion where someone said use `node server.js` to start the server. This WORKED. Before I was using `nodemon server.js` and `npm start`. I've no idea why those commands weren't able to connect to my proxy at `http://127.0.0.1:5000` but `node server.js` could.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think Server not working properly, you should run client and server concurrently for that add following procedures in **`package.json`** file

1) Install concurrently

```
npm install concurrently --save
```

2) configure client and server

```
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client"
```

3) configure concurrently

```
"dev": "concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are not using concurrently at your server side then simply run each front-end and back-end separately such that server side should run first and  client side last.

Comment: Thank you! This answer actually helped me.

Answer (score 2):

This has something to do with default settings of create-react-app.

I found a solution from [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3823). Read the response by danielmahon on 15 Mar 2018

```
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://localhost:5002",
      "secure": false
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing `localhost` to `[::1]` solved my problem.

Taken from here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/proxy-error-with-vue-config-js-and-axios/110632/4?u=mahmoodvcs

Answer (score 1):

If you can't connect to localhost on port 5000 via telnet (you can download and use [PuttY](http://www.putty.org/) if you don't have telnet installed), then that means that server isn't running.

If you're using a Windows machine, go to your package.json for the server that is running on port 5000 and change this line:

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/concurrently \"./node_modules/.bin/nodemon\" \"npm run client\"",
```

To this:

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
```

Watch your build messages and you should see something similar to the following:

```
[0]   ==> API Server now listening on PORT 5000!
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1]
[1] You can now view chat app in the browser.
[1]
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000/
[1]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.118:3000/
[1]
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was trying to run my react project with docker containers open.

Change the ports or shut down the containers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I have been accessing the PORT by the wrong name, i had it PORT instead of SERVER_PORT which was my correct environment variable name. So this problem means that there is a something wrong in your code, in my case the port on which the server should be running was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /signup from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8282/. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

I got the same issue and I just solved it by only restart both of the server, you need to run both of the server running.

Thanks me ltr:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using axios, using proxy might not work sometimes. To fix that, we need to configure our axios before sending requests. axios has a `create()` method, which we can use to set the baseURL.

Create a new file `http.js` in your src folder:

```
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
export default http;
```

Now instead of importing from axios, use this:

```
import axios from "../../http";
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had started server with nodemon and it was not installed on my pc.After install nodemon,it worked :)

```
npm install -g nodemon # or using yarn: yarn global add nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error when waiting for a response from my rest API function which does not return any.

so you either need to change the API implementation and send something back to the client or just don't wait for a response if you are not returning any.

Answer (score 0):

For me proxy should go from http://localhost:3000 to https://localhost:3001 . I changed the second one from https to http, so that in my package.json file is written now:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

I am not sure if this is the correct solution as I am taking a more insecure protocol, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because node 18 uses ipv6 as default, and it have A LOT of different issues. The actual problem raised because the proxy server resolves localhost to ipv6 and your node server don't know who to handle it.

You can solved it by adding `NODE_OPTIONS=\"--dns-result-order=ipv4first\"` to your package.json start script as the following:

```json
...

scripts: {
"start": "NODE_OPTIONS=\"--dns-result-order=ipv4first\" react-scripts start",
"build": "...."
}

...
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I changed port number from 5000 to 7000, while reactjs was still fetching on localhost 5000, after I changed everything worked perfect

ReactJs FETCH HOOK:

```
    const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "http://localhost:7000/api/hotels/countByCity?cities=Arusha,Dodoma,Mwanza,Dar-es-salaam"
  );
```

NodeJS server port:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7000;
```