# Dockerize React app and Go API - Proxy Problem

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize my React app with Go API and I faced with the following error.

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/todos from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

So I found this on google that I need to add those lines in to my package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080","secure": false,
```

I have tried couple of other alternatives around above solution but didn't work out as well.

If I start my Go API in the container and if I start my React app from console with npm start, It does work. But If I try to compose them that is not working.
Any advice appreciated!

My docker-compose.yml;

```
version: '3'
services:
  go:
    build: backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  react:
    build: frontend
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "8080:3000"
```

Here is my backend docker;

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY main.go . 
RUN go get -v -u github.com/gorilla/mux
RUN go build main.go
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

And the my frontend docker;

```
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY /package*.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: localhost refers to the react container, not the go container. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is the docker-compose port mapping

```
version: '3'
services:
  go:
    build: backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  react:
    build: frontend
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
```

this property in package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

works in developement mode, not in production

**Answer to proxy react request to backend**

To proxy your request i think you shoud use another strategy

- create a front-end server that implements the proxy (here an example) https://gist.github.com/saniaky/3a5e68acc2b1ee69ed49b6a3eaee094a

OR

- add another container with nginx as reverse proxy (here an article that explain something similar to your case https://medium.com/@frontendfoo/docker-react-express-reverse-proxy-15d7b37f8dc2)

```
version: '3'
services:
  go:
    build: backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  react:
    build: frontend
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"

   revproxy:
    build: ../docker-reverseProxy
    image: "reverseproxy:1.0.0"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /api {
    proxy_pass         http://backend/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://frontend;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

with reverse proxy you can map a request to a specific path (/api as example) to another server (your server exposed on :8080).

With the above configuration with docker compose you will expose your front on path / (:80) and your back on /api (:80)

**UPDATE**

I try the solution that i suggest in my last comment, the correct proxy configuration shoud be this (considerig the first strategy that i suggest)

```
....
    api: {
        target: 'http://go',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/',
        },
    },
....
```

In this way the internal routing of docker compose will be routed to the container called "go" (the name that you assign in your docker compose)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @dna, 
I have followed your first suggestion with following example;https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561293/6565365
It is still working on localhost but on docker.
I believe what I am missing is on the frontend/Dockerfile as I also tried to dockerize frontend side separately but that didn't worked as well.

Comment: I think the problem is call localhost from a container, since localhost is not reachable from the container, you can try to call your backend with http://go:8080 (this beacuse you are in a docker-compose environvent) https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request to `http://localhost:8080/` from inside your `react` container, your system checks if it can resolve that URI.
The issue is that the only thing that is accessible from **inside** `react` is port 3000. There is nothing on the localhost of `react` on port 8080.
However, the service `go` is accessible on the address `http://localhost:8080/` from the host's machine.

Docker uses [its own DNS](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) for containers, and you have to be aware of how this works.
To solve the issue, add a network to `react` and `go` containers on your docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  go:
    build: backend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - some_network
  react:
    build: frontend
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - some_network

networks:
  some_network:
```

Now that your containers can communicate, change the proxy in the package.json file to:

`"proxy": "http://go:8080"`

This will direct the traffic to the `go` container on port 8080, as Docker will look up the domain called `go` on its embedded DNS server.