# Cannot fetch image from the frontend when added proxy in package.json. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, localhost

Initially, without adding a proxy in the frontend in the package.json, the app works completely fine.

But when I add the proxy,

```
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
```

the app cannot fetch images from the public folder.
And show this error all over for all images. 
I am using node js for the backend.
[image]

I have my image here in this directory.
[image]
Why is it?
Is it anything to do with the image path?

Comment: Can you show the request's headers, particularly the URL it sends to?

Comment: @EldarB. I solved it using this answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500.