# proxy server working in one case and failed in another case

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, proxy-server

So i am working on eCommerce website in react and Node. coming to the point, at the time of login the proxy works totally fine but when i made get request to API it shows an error. I spent 2 days resolving this but at last came here with the hope to get the answer. [image: This is error i got] 
 
[image: brief description of request]

My **server.js** file

```
const express = require ( 'express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const {sequelize} = require('./models')
const  cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded());

// app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
const FarmerRoutes = require('./Routes/Farmer'); // Finished
const AdminRoutes = require('./Routes/Entities'); //  Finished
const Ecommerce = require('./Routes/Ecommerce'); // Finished
const upload = require('./Controllers/ImageManagement')
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(express.static('backend/uploads'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send(" CattleTalk Api is active and running...")
})

app.use('/api/ecommerce',Ecommerce);
app.use('/api/admin',AdminRoutes); 
app.use('/api/farmers',FarmerRoutes);




app.listen(5002,async()=>{
    console.log("The app listening at 5002");
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database Connection has been established successfully.');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
      }
});
```

My **package.json** at frontend looks like this

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "secure":false,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-bootstrap-sidebar": "^0.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5002/"
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing additional `/` from the backend API? Try with `api/ecommerce?city=......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of exploring the internet i couldn't get the answer of my problem, but debugging the code i found the problem. Actually it was one extra trailing slash in URL which made it to misbehave.
I was like this before.

[image: Wrong Link]

[image]

The correct version will be.

[image: correct Link]

[image]

**EXTRA NOTE:**
All those who have not found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500) should move forward to this [link](https://ahrefs.com/blog/trailing-slash/) and look for trailing slash if found in your current URL, for making successful proxy you need to eliminate that trailing slash at the end of URL.