# Error React Proxy error: Could not proxy request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, proxy

Why do I got this error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/management/me from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED).

Got this axios setting:

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

And set this in `package.json`:

```js
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

tried also:

```js
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
```

And have following call:

```js
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "api/v1/management/me",
  data: {},
  headers: { crossDomain: true },
})
```

When I call directly `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/management/me` I got response from server.

I have following backend, Vapor route setting. Maybe something wrong / specific here?

```
let protectedAPIRouter = authSessionRouter.grouped("api/v1").grouped(User.guardAuthMiddleware())
let managementAPIRouter = protectedAPIRouter.grouped("management")
```

Comment: Assuming your server is running [what happens if you add in a closing `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500): `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`?

Comment: None of this hint helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following solutions:

1. Try to change `localhost` to IP address: `"proxy": "http://your_IP_address:8080"`
2. Try this construction also:

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/*":  {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: I had the same problem and it worked after setting 127.0.0.0 instead of localhost

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the package.json over the client project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a proxy to the backend service you want to access.

1. First install (http-proxy-middleware) package.
2. Remove the ("proxy": "http://localhost:8080/") or the Url behind the proxy in the package json file.
3. In the src folder create a file (setupProxy.js) and and the following code.

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8080',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```