# ASP.NET Core 6 Server running on different ports

Tags: reactjs, port, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm getting a proxy error

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/auth/signin from localhost:51171 to http://localhost:3000/

I have noticed that on the starting the server is running on two different ports...

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Starting create-react-app server on port 51171...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
```

In the `package.json` I defined the proxy as follows:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

Comment: Try to refer this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed proxy to: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` and now its working...
Still dont know why smth is running on 51171