# How to use localhost explicitly as a server and in the same time allow proxying React app to backend in Go?

Tags: reactjs, go, networking, proxy

I have a backend written in Go. All works fine and calls from POSTMAN are passing, but suddenly I cannot have React app calling this server because of error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /login from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED).
```

My go server code:

```
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("localhost:8080"), api.router))
```

The package.json of React app looks like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

I know that I could bind with all interfaces in Go like this:

```
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":8080"), api.router))
```

But then Mac OS asks me to Allow this connection and I cannot do it since I'm not the administrator on the computer

I could do it with codesign, but I don't have currently any identities so generating private key, adding it to key chain would also take some time

Any easy way to bypass this?

Comment: try to change this localhost to `3000` in `fmt.Sprintf("localhost:3000")`  that go server could listen the frontend (React)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a slash at the end of the react proxy line, like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
```

This above was found in a similar question to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532447/14737445)

Also, you can try changing the proxy from localhost to 127.0.0.1:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```