# Proxy error: could not proxy request /api/notes from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, proxy

I am trying to show NoteList app using reactJS, I am getting this error-
proxy error: could not proxy request /api/notes from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/.

In package.json file I have set proxy as-

"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

I have also checked for the port availability using netstat, but these all seems to be correct. Can anybody help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not proxy request /pusher/auth from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367298/could-not-proxy-request-pusher-auth-from-localhost3000-to-http-localhost500)